# Expected value of indicator function of random variable Y multiplied with function of random variable X

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

I have a random variable $X$, a function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and the indicator function $1\{Y \le a \}$ where "$a$" is a real number. Is there a general way to calculate the expected value $E( g(X) * 1\{Y \le a \} )$? I'm not sure how to approach this sort of thing.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: When I posed the question I didn't mean for them to be independent but if it works with independent variables it would probably also help me with my problem, just in a different way I originally intended. So if you know how to go about it that would be great!

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then so are $g(X)$ and $\mathbf1(Y\leq a)$, so 
$$\mathbb E[g(X)\cdot\mathbf1(Y\leq a)]=\mathbb E[g(X)]\cdot\mathbb E[\mathbf1(Y\leq a)]=\mathbb E[g(X)]\cdot\mathbb P(Y\leq a).$$
We can compute $\mathbb E[g(X)]$ via the law of the unconscious statistician, i.e. 
$$\mathbb E[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}F_X(x).$$

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't know it followed that g(X)  and 1(Y≤a)  are independent. Can you explain why that is the case or is that a longer proof?

Comment: In general, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then so are $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$, where $g$ and $h$ are functions. This is because if we take (measurable) sets $A,B\subset\mathbb R$, then we have $g(X)\in A\iff X\in g^{-1}(A)$ and $h(Y)\in B\iff Y\in h^{-1}(B)$, where $g^{-1},h^{-1}$ denote the pre-images. So
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(g(X)\in A\cap h(Y)\in B)&=\mathbb P(X\in g^{-1}(A)\cap Y\in h^{-1}(B))\\
&=\mathbb P(X\in g^{-1}(A))\cdot\mathbb P(Y\in h^{-1}(B)) \\
&=\mathbb P(g(X)\in A)\cdot\mathbb P(h(Y)\in B).
\end{align*}
In this question, we take $h(Y)=\mathbf1(Y\leq a)$.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help! Everything is clear now.